# How to avoid code duplication when defining many objects with various characteristics?

Tags: objective-c

I think this must be a very common problem in game programming where you have lots of characters with various capabilities.

I am using protocols to define actions for characters wherever feasible and inheritance when I need objects to share large blocks of code. The problem with protocols is that they only define the interface, so implementation is often duplicate code. Is there a better approach to this problem, or in this case is it acceptable to have *some* code duplication? There's no multiple inheritance in Objective-C, so that's out of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem with inheritance in game design. You can try using [components](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html) instead. There are different ways to implement a component based system, but generally a game entity is a container of components and you can easily reuse components for different entities. Here are some more resources you might find useful:

- [Evolve your hierarchy](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/)
- [Game object structure : inheritance vs. aggregation](http://www.gamearchitect.net/Articles/GameObjects1.html)
- [Powerpoint presentation from GDC Canada](http://cmpmedia.vo.llnwd.net/o1/vault/gdccanada09/slides/marcinchadyGDCCanada.ppt)
- [Component based entity system design](http://www.purplepwny.com/blog/?p=215)

Comment: I'm fairly new to this components idea. Great reading material!

Answer (score 1):

> "I think this must be a very common
>   problem in game programming where you
>   have lots of characters with various
>   capabilities."

No, generally not. It sounds like you're creating new classes or types for each variety of character in the game, whereas normally we just create a Character class and implement the different behaviour via different methods, or interchangeable behaviour classes. If there is wildly differing behaviour then it's common to put those in scripts written in a different language. The many permutations of differing capabilities is essentially a data problem, not a code problem.